# What is the time complexity of Trsm and other BLAS operations?

Tags: time, time-complexity, linear-algebra, benchmarking, blas

I am accelerating a model by replacing all its linear algebra operations with cuBlas's functions. And I want to get the time complexity or FLOPs of the model to evaluate its performance in roofline model.

There are two kinds of operation in the model: **Gemm and Trsm**.

I know the FLOPs of Gemm is about 2 * k * m * n from the question : [How to compute the achieved FLOPS of a MPI program which calls cuBlas function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73590913/how-to-compute-the-achieved-flops-of-a-mpi-program-which-calls-cublas-function):

> The standard BLAS GEMM operation is C <- alpha * (A dot B) + beta * C and for A (m by k), B (k by n) and C (m by n), each inner product of a row of A and a column of B multiplied by alpha is 2 * k + 1 flop and there are m * n inner products in A dot B and another 2 * m * n flop for adding beta * C to that dot product. So the total model FLOP count is (2 * k + 3) * (m * n) when alpha and beta are both non-zero.

But for Trsm, I have no idea about its computation complexity. All the documents I found say it's about O(n^3) which isn't clear enough to get the computation complexity.

Sincerely thank you for your answers!

Comment: `O(n^3)` IS the computational complexity.  If you want to know the actual runtime, you should do some benchmarking.

Comment: @TimRoberts I want to know a more specific model count of the time complexity, like 2 * m * n * k for gemm. Because to get the work of the model, I need to sum up the operations' FLOPs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But for Trsm, I have no idea about its computation complexity. All the documents I found say it's about O(n^3) which isn't clear enough to get the computation complexity.

It's about O(n^2) not O(n^3).

TRSM performs a number of different implementation depending on the form of the matrix, but for the canonical `B <- alpha * inv(A) dot B` where B is (m by n) and A is a non-unit upper triangular matrix, the operation count should be something like `n * (3/2*m + 1)` [n diagonal scaling operations plus 1/2 * 3 * m * n operations over all the non-zero row entries]

If you want to know the exact FLOP count for the reference implementation of any of the BLAS or LAPACK routines, the obvious way to do it is inspect the [reference serial code](https://netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d1/d54/group__double__blas__level3_ga6a0a7704f4a747562c1bd9487e89795c.html) and count the floating point operations, either by hand or by instrumentation of the code itself.